# jQuery animated hover blinking out of control

Tags: jquery, hover, jquery-animate

I'm using the following code as a hover-function on thumbnails:

```
$(function (){      
  $('.button').hover(function() {  
    if ($(this).is(":not(animated)")) {
      $(this).animate({opacity: 0.7}, 'fast');
    }
  },
  function() {
    $(this).animate({opacity: 1}, 'fast' );
  });
});
```

The problem is that when I pass over a thumb too fast, the effect keeps blinking for a while...  Is there something I can add to the if block to prevent this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `stop()` to stop the current animation before starting a new one, it should work:

```
$(function (){      
    $('.button').hover(function() {  
        $(this).stop().animate({opacity: 0.7}, 'fast');
    },
    function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({opacity: 1}, 'fast' );
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can force effects not to be queued:

```
$(function() {
   $('.button').hover(function(){ 
        $(this).animate({opacity: 0.7}, { duration: 'fast', queue: false });
    },
    function(){
        $(this).animate({opacity: 1}, { duration: 'fast', queue: false } );
    }
);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The [hoverIntent plugin](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) serves that purpose, check it out. To apply it with default options, you would simply change:

```
$('.button').hover(function(){
```

to:

```
$('.button').hoverIntent(function(){
```

Comment: thx for the answer... prefer not to need any more plugins tho. So I'm going with the 2nd answer :)